# How to properly use "setComponentModifierValue" command to set an array of doubles in OpenModelica

Tags: python, openmodelica

```
   **DICTIONARY CONTENTS CHANGE ORDER! WHY ?**
```

The contents of the dictionary I assign change order! 
I assign Fc= {0.25, 0.4, 0.1, 0.001, 0.0491, 0.06} and then in the Python 3.6.7 Shell I get Fc = '{0.25, 0.4, 0.1, 0.06, 0.0491, 0.001}'. Why is this happening? 
My purpose is to use setComponentModifierValue command to change the modifiers' values of a simulation.

I have only found an example with a variable b=0.5 omc.sendExpression("setComponentModifierValue(structure_test_final_no_payload, Fc, $Code(="+str(b)+"))"), but what happens when somebody wants to change an array. n

In OpenModelica Fc is defined as:
 parameter Real Fc[6] = {0.55, 1.2, 0.5, 0.05, 0.0491, 0.08}

and the result of 
omc.sendExpression("getComponentModifierValue(structure_test_final_no_payload, Fc)") 
is 
'{0.55, 1.2, 0.5, 0.05, 0.0491, 0.08}'

Instead of '{0.25,0.4,0.1,0.001,0.0491,0.06}'

I get '{0.25, 0.4, 0.1, 0.06, 0.0491, 0.001}'

Answer (score 1):

Don't use curly braces { ... } in Python, those are sets with no order. Use lists instead.

```
from OMPython import OMCSessionZMQ
omc = OMCSessionZMQ()
x = omc.sendExpression("cd()")
print("Got:" + str(x) + "\n");  
loadFile = "loadFile(\"" + str(x) + "/m.mo\")"
print("loadFile: " + loadFile + "\n")
x = omc.sendExpression(loadFile)
print("Got:" + str(x) + "\n")
x = omc.sendExpression("getErrorString()")
print("Got:" + str(x) + "\n")
x = omc.sendExpression("getComponentModifierValue(structure_test_final_no_payload, Fc)")
print("Got:" + str(x) + "\n")

Fc= [0.25, 0.4, 0.1, 0.001, 0.0491, 0.06]
print("Fc: " + str(Fc) + "\n")
strFc = "{" + ",".join(map(str, Fc)) + "}"
print("strFc: " + strFc + "\n")
x = omc.sendExpression("setComponentModifierValue(structure_test_final_no_payload, Fc, $Code(="+strFc+"))")
print("Got:" + str(x) + "\n")
x = omc.sendExpression("getErrorString()")
print("Got:" + str(x) + "\n")
x = omc.sendExpression("getComponentModifierValue(structure_test_final_no_payload, Fc)")
print("Got:" + str(x) + "\n")
x = omc.sendExpression("list(structure_test_final_no_payload)")
print("Got:" + str(x) + "\n")
```

The result of running this is:

```
$ /e/bin/python64/python test.py
2019-01-22 22:56:23,647 - OMPython - INFO - OMC Server is up and running at file:///c:/users/adrpo33/appdata/local/temp/openmodelica.port.558379ad46714b13bcd0c6aeb065c0a4 pid=22996
Got:C:/home/adrpo33/dev/OMTesting/python
loadFile: loadFile("C:/home/adrpo33/dev/OMTesting/python/m.mo")
Got:True
Got:
Got:{0.55, 1.2, 0.5, 0.05, 0.0491, 0.08}
Fc: [0.25, 0.4, 0.1, 0.001, 0.0491, 0.06]    
strFc: {0.25,0.4,0.1,0.001,0.0491,0.06}    
Got:Ok    
Got:    
Got:{0.25, 0.4, 0.1, 0.001, 0.0491, 0.06}
Got:model structure_test_final_no_payload
  parameter Real Fc[6] = {0.25, 0.4, 0.1, 0.001, 0.0491, 0.06};
end structure_test_final_no_payload;
```

File m.mo contains:

```
model structure_test_final_no_payload
  parameter Real Fc[6] = {0.55, 1.2, 0.5, 0.05, 0.0491, 0.08};
end structure_test_final_no_payload;
```